# Error in predict.NaiveBayes : "Not all variable names used in object found in newdata"-- (Although no variables are missing)

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, r-caret, naivebayes, least-squares

I'm still learning to use `caret` package through [The caret Package by Max Kuhn](https://topepo.github.io/caret/#) and got stuck in [16.2 Partial Least Squares Discriminant Analysis](https://topepo.github.io/caret/miscellaneous-model-functions.html#partial-least-squares-discriminant-analysis) section while trying to predict using the `plsBayesFit` model through `predict(plsBayesFit, head(testing), type = "prob")` as shown in the book as well.

The data used is `data(Sonar)` from `mlbench` package, with the data being split as:

```
inTrain <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = 2/3, list = FALSE)

sonarTrain <- Sonar[ inTrain, -ncol(Sonar)]
sonarTest  <- Sonar[-inTrain, -ncol(Sonar)]

trainClass <- Sonar[ inTrain, "Class"]
testClass  <- Sonar[-inTrain, "Class"]
```

and then preprocessed as follows:

```
centerScale <- preProcess(sonarTrain)
centerScale

training <- predict(centerScale, sonarTrain)
testing <- predict(centerScale, sonarTest)
```

after this the model is trained using `plsBayesFit <- plsda(training, trainClass, ncomp = 20, probMethod = "Bayes")`, followed by predicted using `predict(plsBayesFit, head(testing), type = "prob")`.

When I'm trying to do this I get the following error:
`Error in predict.NaiveBayes(object$probModel[[ncomp[i]]], as.data.frame(tmpPred[,  : Not all variable names used in object found in newdata`

I've checked both the training and testing sets to check for any missing variable but there isn't any. I've also tried to predict using the 2.7.1 version of `pls` package which was used to render the book at that time but that too is giving me same error. What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to replicate your problem using different models, as I have encountered this `error` as well, but I failed; and `caret` seems to behave differently now from when I used it.

In any case stumbled upon this `Github`-issues [here](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/2738), and it seems like that there is a specific problem with the `klaR`-package. So my guess is that this is simply a `bug` - and nothing that can be readily fixed here!

Comment: Ah, that's a disappointment. I'll try and see if using previous version of `klaR` will do it. I didn't check the `backtrace()` to know that `klaR` was causing it. Thought that it was `pls`. Anyway, thanks man.